# Nullpointerexception in Volley JsonObjectRequest

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception, android-volley

I am stuck trying to perform a simple JsonObjectRequest inside the Genymotion Emulator using Google volley. But the last line of the code below (instantiation of `JsonObjectRequest`) leads to a Nullpointerexception.

Could anyone please explain what I am missing here?

```
JSONObject requestParams = new JSONObject();
try{
    requestParams.put("username","aaaa");
    requestParams.put("password","bbbb");
}catch(JSONException e){
    e.printStackTrace();
}

Response.Listener<JSONObject> listener = new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
@Override
    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
        //Do something
    }
};

Response.ErrorListener errorListener = new Response.ErrorListener(){
    @Override
    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError volleyError) {
    }
};

JsonObjectRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, "192.168.178.155/user", requestParams, listener, errorListener);
```

**Logcat**

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.android.volley.Request.<init>(Request.java:129)
        at com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonRequest.<init>(JsonRequest.java:58)
        at com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonObjectRequest.<init>(JsonObjectRequest.java:48)
        at my.package.name.RequestHandler.performRequest(RequestHandler.java:68)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to include `http://` in your URL:

i.e. do

```
request = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, "http://192.168.178.155/user", requestParams, listener, errorListener);
```

instead of

```
request = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, "192.168.178.155/user", requestParams, listener, errorListener);
```

Comment: @MartinGolpashin no prob - in the future, you'll generally need to include `http://` anytime you're passing a String to a method that's going to derive a URL from it.